# How to use Gnuplot to create histogram from binned data from CSV file?

Tags: csv, gnuplot, data-visualization

I have a CSV file which is generated by a process that outputs the data in pre-defined bins (say from -100 to +100 in steps of 10). So, each line looks somewhat like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
```

i.e. 20 comma separated values, the first representing the frequency in the range -100 to -90, while the last represents the frequency between 90 to 100.

The problem is, Gnuplot seems to require the raw data for it to be able to generate a histogram, whereas I have only the frequency distribution. How do I proceed in this case? I'm looking for the simplest possible histogram, that perhaps displays the data using vertical bars.

Answer (score 0):

You already have histogram data, so you mustn't use "set histogram".
Generate the x-values from the linenumbers, and do a simple boxplot

```
plot dataf using (($0-10)*10):$1 with boxes
```

Comment: Can u specify how to "Generate the x-values"? Is it done with `($0-10)*10`? In my case, should it not be `($0-10)*20` ?

Comment: Have you tried to work this out by yourself at all? RTFM, and start with "help using".